# In Unity Android Development, in situation that updating App, but no changes in Bundle

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, assetbundle, app-update

When updating my app, if there is no changes on the bundle, how to not download the bundle after updating app? Using Unity addressable bundle and build to aab.

1. Pre-version start down bundle
2. Next version updating, and just look download bundle again.

I expect if there is no changes on the bundle, it should only do an app update.